# Visual Studio Code Typescript not compiling on save

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm struggling to get Visual Studio Code to compile my TypeScript to Javascript.  I've been successfully working with TS in Visual Studio 2017, however I thought I'd give VS Code a try.

I've got the watch task running, the last line in the terminal output is:

`15:57:49 - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.`

However, when I save a ts file, nothing is happening.  Again, in VS2017, it compiles on save fine.

There are areas of the project that produce a fair few TS errors - these are areas that have been written by others and are out of the scope of my project.  I'm wondering if these errors would be stopping the compilation?  Or should it still compile on a file-by-file basis?

**ts.config**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "typings/ckeditor/ckeditor.d.ts",
    "typings/ckeditor/index.d.ts",
    "typings/lodash/lodash.d.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ] 
}
```

**Versions**

VSCode 1.17.2

Typescript 2.5.3

Comment: do u face with an error?

Comment: @Salman Other than the linting errors from the other projects, nope.

Comment: so, how do u know they do not stop transpiling process?

Comment: @Salman I don't know if they're stopping them, that's part of my question :) However it seems strange that VS 2017 compiles them fine.

Comment: i would add my suggested solution to in few minutes

Comment: You defined `"noEmitOnError": true` so if you have typescript errors js won't be generated

Comment: @AlekseyL.That fixed it!  Think I'd put that in ages ago when figuring out `tsconfig` without realising what it is!  Want to make a solution and i'll mark it the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"noEmitOnError": true` compiler option prevents javascript generation in case typescript errors found.

More on compiler options [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)